# SVG Rendering Error

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I've made a vector graphic in Illustrator and cannot seem to get it to show up after saving it as SVG 1.1. I keep on getting this error, and it has made it so that my entire graphic won't even show up:

```
error on line 8 at column 93: Namespace prefix inkscape for connector-curvature 
on path is not defined
```

I'm not exactly sure what that means and I've looked in the SVG code and cannot figure out what to do to fix it.

What does that error mean and how do I get rid of it?

Thank you - responses are much appreciated!

Comment: This is a known failure of Illustrator; in the "SVG Options" window when exporting the SVG in Illustrator, click "More options" then untick "Output fewer <tspan> elements" as well as "Include slicing data". This should solve it. If people upvote this comment I will turn it into an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your file has elements with the inkscape namespace, that suggests it has originated in Inkscape.  Or have you perhaps merged in part of an SVG that came from Inkscape?

What this error suggests is that the file has inkscape attributes without the inkscape namespace being defined.

Try this: go through the file and delete any attributes of the form `inkscape:whatever="something"`.  That should solve your problem.

If it doesn't, you may need to post the file somewhere so we can look at it.

Comment: Alternative: open the svg file in Inkscape, then save it as "Optimized SVG" (in the save-as dialog).

Answer (score 1):

The file was created in Inkscape and placed in Illustrator, so it preserved the namespace declaration. Instead of editing the file by hand, try to do something to the image to make illustrator re-stroke-and-fill it. For example, Merge in pathfinder. If you can get Illustrator to remake it in its own way, the namespace will drop off.